# How to convert azure vision output in string Json to previous object?

Tags: c#, json, ocr, azure-cognitive-services

I have converted the input image into OCRResults by using these codes.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts-sdk/client-library?tabs=visual-studio&pivots=programming-language-csharp

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision;
using Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision.Models;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Linq;

namespace ComputerVisionQuickstart
{
    class Program
    {
        // Add your Computer Vision subscription key and endpoint
        static string subscriptionKey = "PASTE_YOUR_COMPUTER_VISION_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY_HERE";
        static string endpoint = "PASTE_YOUR_COMPUTER_VISION_ENDPOINT_HERE";

        private const string READ_TEXT_URL_IMAGE = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-sample-data-files/master/ComputerVision/Images/printed_text.jpg";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Azure Cognitive Services Computer Vision - .NET quickstart example");
            Console.WriteLine();

            ComputerVisionClient client = Authenticate(endpoint, subscriptionKey);

            // Extract text (OCR) from a URL image using the Read API
            ReadFileUrl(client, READ_TEXT_URL_IMAGE).Wait();
        }

        public static ComputerVisionClient Authenticate(string endpoint, string key)
        {
            ComputerVisionClient client =
              new ComputerVisionClient(new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials(key))
              { Endpoint = endpoint };
            return client;
        }

        public static async Task ReadFileUrl(ComputerVisionClient client, string urlFile)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("READ FILE FROM URL");
            Console.WriteLine();

            // Read text from URL
            var textHeaders = await client.ReadAsync(urlFile);
            // After the request, get the operation location (operation ID)
            string operationLocation = textHeaders.OperationLocation;
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            // Retrieve the URI where the extracted text will be stored from the Operation-Location header.
            // We only need the ID and not the full URL
            const int numberOfCharsInOperationId = 36;
            string operationId = operationLocation.Substring(operationLocation.Length - numberOfCharsInOperationId);

            // Extract the text
            ReadOperationResult results;
            Console.WriteLine($"Extracting text from URL file {Path.GetFileName(urlFile)}...");
            Console.WriteLine();
            do
            {
                results = await client.GetReadResultAsync(Guid.Parse(operationId));
            }
            while ((results.Status == OperationStatusCodes.Running ||
                results.Status == OperationStatusCodes.NotStarted));

            // Display the found text.
            Console.WriteLine();
            var textUrlFileResults = results.AnalyzeResult.ReadResults;
            foreach (ReadResult page in textUrlFileResults)
            {
                foreach (Line line in page.Lines)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line.Text);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

    }
}
```

If I converting the output from the azure vision into json.Is any possibilities convert the json to previous object?

Comment: What do you mean by "convert the json to previous object?" ? C# object?

Comment: Hi Nicolas,
If I convert the Student object to JSON, How can I get another object like the Employee object from the same JSON?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what those "Student" and "Employee" object are, and their link to Azure Cognitive Services

Comment: If i convert the ReadOperationResult results; (taken from the above code snippet) into JSON.
I already have the OCR class , so how do I convert Json to my ocr class?